# How can I use customized vertices (vertex with info) for triangulation on sphere in CGAL?

Tags: cgal, triangulation

I want to use customized vertices for triangulation on sphere.
In user manual, customized vertices can be used for 2D triangulation like this:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, K>    Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb>                    Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds>                      Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                             Point;

int main() {
   std::vector<std::pair<Point, unsigned>> points;
   Delaunay dt;
   dt.insert(points.begin(), points.end());
   return 0;
}
```

I want to use customized vertices for Delaunay triangulation on sphere too, but couldn't find ways to use it.
What I want to do is like this:

```cpp
CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits> dtos;
std::vector<std::pair<Point, unsigned>> points;
dtos.insert(points.begin(), points.end());
```

I tried using Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_with_info_2 which is created based on Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2 referring to "Triangulation_vertex_base_with info_2.h" file, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for reading.

---

Following Mael's suggestion, I wrote a code below but failed to compile. What should I fix? Thank you so much for your reply.

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                 K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_traits_2<K>                  Traits;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2<Traits>                 Vbb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, Traits, Vbb>  Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_face_base_2<Traits>                   Cb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Cb>                        Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits, Tds>               DToS2;
typedef DToS2::Point_3                                                      Point;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<Point, unsigned>> points;
    points.emplace_back(Point(-1, 0, 0), 0);
    points.emplace_back(Point(0, -1, 0), 1);
    points.emplace_back(Point(0, 0, -1), 2);
    points.emplace_back(Point(1, 0, 0), 3);
    points.emplace_back(Point(0, 1, 0), 4);
    points.emplace_back(Point(0, 0, 1), 5);
    
    DToS2 dt;
    dt.insert(points.begin(), points.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Here is build output:

```
>------ Build All started: Project: kitti2discarto, Configuration: x64-Release ------
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\kitti2discarto.dir\main.cpp.obj
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/kitti2discarto.dir/main.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1431~1.311\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DCGAL_USE_GMPXX=1 -DDISABLE_QHULL -DGLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES -DNOMINMAX -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SILENCE_CXX17_ITERATOR_BASE_CLASS_DEPRECATION_WARNING -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__SSE__ -D__SSSE3__ -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\eigen3 -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\openni2 -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0 -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\qt5 -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\qt5\QtWidgets -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\qt5\QtGui -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\qt5\QtCore -external:I C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\tools\qt5\mkspecs\win32-msvc -external:W0 /std:c++20 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG   /bigobj -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /bigobj /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\kitti2discarto.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\kitti2discarto.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\User\workspace\kitti2discarto\kitti2discarto\main.cpp
C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL\Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2.h(635): error C2338: (std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Point>::value)
  C:\Users\User\workspace\kitti2discarto\kitti2discarto\main.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned __int64 CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits,Tds>::insert<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>>(InputIterator,InputIterator,void *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::pair<Point,unsigned int>,
              InputIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::pair<Point,unsigned int>>>>
          ]
  C:\Users\User\workspace\kitti2discarto\kitti2discarto\main.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned __int64 CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits,Tds>::insert<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>>(InputIterator,InputIterator,void *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::pair<Point,unsigned int>,
              InputIterator=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::pair<Point,unsigned int>>>>
          ]
C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL\Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2.h(636): error C2338: !(std::is_same<Point, Point_3>::value)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

---

Sharing the results:

This is an example made according to Mael's comments. It works fine!

```cpp
#include <isotream>
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                 K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_traits_2<K>                  Traits;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2<Traits>                 Vbb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<size_t, Traits, Vbb>    Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_face_base_2<Traits>                   Cb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Cb>                        Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits, Tds>               DToS2;
typedef DToS2::Point_3                                                      Point;
typedef DToS2::Vertex_handle                                                VH;

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points;
    points.emplace_back(-1, 0, 0);
    points.emplace_back(0, -1, 0);
    points.emplace_back(0, 0, -1);
    points.emplace_back(1, 0, 0);
    points.emplace_back(0, 1, 0);
    points.emplace_back(0, 0, 1);
    
    Traits traits(Point(0, 0, 0), 1);
    DToS2 dt(traits);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        const VH vh = dt.insert(points[i]);
        if (vh != VH()) vh->info() = i;
    }

    for (DToS2::Finite_faces_iterator face_itr = dt.finite_faces_begin(); face_itr != dt.finite_faces_end(); face_itr++) {
        std::cout << face_itr->vertex(0)->info() << ", " << face_itr->vertex(1)->info() << ", " << face_itr->vertex(2)->info() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine vertex bases like this

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;

typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_traits_2<K>  Traits;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_vertex_base_2<Traits> Vbb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, Traits, Vbb> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_on_sphere_face_base_2<Traits> Cb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Cb> Tds;

typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_on_sphere_2<Traits, Tds> DToS2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to apply your suggestion but encountered another issue. When I compile my code, an error occured with this message: error C2338: (std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Point>::value)

Comment: Triangulations on the sphere do not yet support zipped insertions like this; you have to insert one by one (`Vertex_handle vh = tr.insert(p); vh->info() = ...`;)

Comment: Note that the only difference between iterative insertion and a range insertion is that the range insertion will optimize the order of insertion such that consecutive insertions are close in space (using Hilbert sort on the sphere), which speeds things up a little. You can apply that independtly and insert one by one, and it will be exactly the same. We will add an example to demonstrate that, but you can find inspiration in the existing range-with-info insertion (https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Triangulation_3/include/CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h#L427)